# Difference between handling missing and null values

Tags: null, missing-data

I have a dataset with a variable indicating how many days has passed (within a limited period of time) till a certain event happens.

Some of the records have null values as that event never happened to them (within that period of time).

When dealing with missing values, sometimes we use imputation with some algorithm or mean, median, etc. In dealing with this kind of null values, however, my intuition is that we should replace those null values with a huge number and use those records in modeling bec those null values provide information too.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You have a variable that contains numeric data, more or less "continuous" data as integers.  Then you have some responses (null/missing) which do not represent a point on this continuum, but rather some qualitative status, i.e., "The event did not happen (yet)" or "Respondent did not answer this question."  I don't really know why you'd want to replace those with some "huge" number. Imputation seems like a better choice, or leave them out and analyze them separately, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: bec it's not that this event didn't happen (yet). It meant that it didn't happen at all and it won't happen in the future. Therefore they are final definite result. And I feel these records with a null value indicating that the event didn't happen can also help predict the response variable.